# Update OS enviroment variables from inside VIM

Tags: cut-copy-paste, tmux, ssh

I use vim inside tmux over an ssh session and I often run into the issue where the `$DISPLAY` variable gets changed, screwing up my copy-paste.

When I log in, $DISPLAY gets assigned to something new: `localhost:B.0` let's say. When this happens, any open tmux pane still has the old DISPLAY saved `localhost:A.0`. Inside tmux that's easy enough to change, just `export DISPLAY=localhost:B.0`

But, any open VIM sessions will also have the old display, `localhost:A.0`. Now, I can quit out, change DISPLAY, and reopen vim, but that's a nuisance.

**Is there a way to change OS environment variables from inside of vim?**

I've tried:
- Suspending vim, `ctr+z`, setting the environment variable and bringing vim back to the foreground, `fg`
- Setting the vim DISPLAY via `:let $DISPLAY='localhost:B.0'`
- Running shell commands from vim `:!export DISPLAY=localhost:B.0`

But these don't work. Are there any other options?

Comment: Im a little confused: perhaps you can clarify your use/need. `DISPLAY` get set correctly for the shell/environment on the machine you login to, and you want that to back-propagate to your original machine? Why? In general, affecting parent environments from a subprocess is tricky and unnecessary.

Comment: Here's some good explanations on the display variable and copy+paste https://stackoverflow.com/a/50608243/1322179, https://gist.github.com/antonkratz/ebfcefdb5fdf266631e4985d65535322#now-if-you-have-vim-running-under-gnu-screen-on-a-remote-machine-with-ssh--y-you-have-a-problem, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard#DISPLAY_environment_variable_on_Linux_systems

Comment: `:let $DISPLAY=...` should work to set the Display environment variable to a new value. However, when done after Vim has started, Vim won't re-initialize the connection to the X-Server, so that practically won't help you. There is currently some discussion on how to fix a broken X connection in Vim: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3649 Please check the mentioned patch and report back.